# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-code-push:compileReleaseAidl'. > Failed to find Build Tools revision 33.0.0

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, signed-apk

I want to generate release apk but I'm receiving this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-code-push:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 33.0.0
```

My Environment is:
System:
OS: macOS 14.0
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 146.61 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.20.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.11.06.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.14.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
Xcode: 15.0.1/15A507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

I have tried signed release in android studio and also `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`
Also try these solutions:

1. add mavenCentral() https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1613#issuecomment-1128011033
2. remove and reinstall sdk buildtools https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvtbUmOBJFY
3. downgrade java version from 21 to 11.0.17
4. update path in local.properties https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fsr2-ti39w

I have debug build but I want release apk